# A continuous nowhere differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I am self-reviewing some basic analysis (undergraduate level), and I stumped upon this question from Abbott's book *Understanding Analysis*:

Let $g$ be a function such that

$$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n} h(2^n x)$$

where

$$h(x) = |x|$$

is defined on the interval $[-1,1]$ and we additionally require that $h(x) = h(x+2)$. The two-part question is the following

> a). Show that $g(x)$ attains maximum on the interval $[0,2]$, say $M$, and find $M$.
>
> b). Define the set $D = \{x \in [0, 2] : g(x) = M\}$. Is the set $D$ finite, countable, or uncountable?

Since $g(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, it is obvious that $g(x)$ will attain maximum and minimum on $[0,2]$, because the closed interval is compact. But I cannot figure out the rest of the problem. Any thought is appreciated.

Comment: $h(x) = |x|$ implies that $h(2^nx) = 2^n |x|$.  Then $$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} h(2^nx) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} 2^{n} |x| = |x| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1, $$ which diverges for all $x \ne 0$, no?  Is there a typo in the definition of $g$ or $h$, perhaps?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, $h$ is defined as $f(x) = |x|$ on $[-1, 1]$ and is extended onto all of $\mathbb{R}$ by the periodicity $h(x+2) = h(x)$.

Comment: Oi... reading comprehension fail.  Sorry.  I'm an idiot.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for the link. The plot is also included in the book. It is possible to show that $g(x)$ converges absolutely for any fixed $x \in R$, but I'm not sure how to find max on a given interval.

Comment: @JackShi Yeah, I realized that after posting the link, and subsequently deleted it.  I'm clearly having trouble braining tonight.  The point is not to actually find the max on a given interval, but characterize how often you get there on the interval $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $k : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $k(x) = h(x) + \frac{1}{2}h(2x)$. Then it is easy to check that

$$ k(x) = \begin{cases}
2x, & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
1, & \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{2} \\
2(2-x), & \frac{3}{2} \leq x \leq 2 \\
k(x \text{ mod } 2), & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} $$

$\hspace{10em}$ [image: graph of h]

Notice that $g$ can be written entirely in terms of $k$:

$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n} k(4^n x). $$

Now let $I_n = 2 \bigcup_{j=0}^{4^n - 1} \frac{1}{4^n}\left( j + \left[ \frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4} \right] \right)$ and notice that this is the set of points in $[0, 2]$ where the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{4^n}k(4^n x)$ attains its maximum. Here comes a crucial observation:

> For each $a = (a_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \in \{1, 2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ we define $x(a) := 2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_j}{4^j}$. Then $x(a) \in I_n$ for all $n \geq 0$.

Indeed, this is because $I_n$ contains all real numbers $x \in [0, 2]$ such that the $(n+1)$-th digit in the $4$-ary expansion of $\frac{x}{2}$ is either $1$ or $2$.

In particular, for each $a \in \{1, 2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ we have

$$ g(x(a))
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n} k(4^n x(a))
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}
= \frac{4}{3} $$

Since $g(x) \leq \frac{4}{3}$ is always true, it follows that $M = \frac{4}{3}$. Moreover, $x(a) \in D$ for any $a \in \{1, 2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. So $x : \{1, 2\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to [0, 2]$ is an injective map whose image lies in $D$ and hence $D$ is uncountable.

Comment: This solution is amazing! Thanks. One question tho: how did you realize to define such a function $k(x)$ in the first place?

Comment: @JackShi, My intuition was that, if you look at even-th steps of the construction (see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlancmangeFunction.html), for example), rescaled copies of $k$ is created and put atop of the previous even-th step. So the flattened top gets shrunken in a similar way the Cantor set is created. This gave me an idea that I may mimic the construction of the Cantor set. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: Hi, the reason I came here is because what I learnt in the book Understanding Analysis simplye doesn't give me enough to answer the question. The more I learn from the book, the more I realize I am lacking behind, for example, the construction and intuition you made. May I ask where can I get this kind of training, e.g.: constructing function whenever it is needed? Also, is it kinda expected for me to construct solution at your maturity after reading 4 chapters only?